# ERROR in The target entry-point "angular-in-memory-web-api" has missing dependencies: - @angular/http

Tags: angular8

iam trying to run i already installed but it showing ERROR in The target entry-point "angular-in-memory-web-api" has missing dependencies:

- @angular/http

Answer (score 1):

Simply run this command:

```
npm install @angular/http --legacy-peer-deps
```